# Why doesn't my regex work in R with grep?

Tags: r, regex, email

I tried to write a code in regex101.com to identify any kind of email address.

The general email address formats are like this:

`rohan.singh@example.com`

`rakesh@example.com`

`hamed.jelveh@example.dd.rr`

This command works in [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) if i want to select just emails among the text.  The regex101.com link is below:
https://regex101.com/r/UA6CTA/1

```
(\w){1,25}(.|\w){1,25}@(\w){1,25}.(\w){1,25}(.|\w|$)((\w){1,25}|$)
```

but when i write this in R even when i use \ insitead of \ with grep command, it gives me "character(0)".
the script is below:

```
emails <- c("javad.rasooli@bpmn.edu",
"education@world.gov",
"babak.pirooz@peace.org",
"invalid.edu",
"sadeghi@apbarez.edu",
"hassaneskandari@codeman.ir")
emails[grep(pattern = r"(\w){1,25}(.|\w){1,25}@(\w){1,25}.(\w){1,25}(.|\w|$)((\w){1,25}|$)",
x=emails)]
```

The output in terminal is below:

```
emails[grep(pattern = r"((\w){1,25}(.|\w){1,25}@(\w){1,25}.
+             (\w){1,25}(.|\w|$)((\w){1,25}|$))",
+             x=emails)]
character(0)
```

> Can anyone help me what to do ?

Comment: The `\\` in your assignment wasn't tested at regex_101, but likely if you do `emails <- c(`, things will go better. What might the compiler think was happening on the left hand side of `<-` when the choices are `email` ' ' `\\`?

Comment: You don't want to validate email addresses, do you? For just extracting e-mails why not use something simple like e.g. [`[^\s@,;]+@[^\s@,;]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dAXcAi/1) (modify to possible separators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the regex used in regex101 was without double backslashes, like this:

```
(\w){1,25}(.|\w){1,25}@(\w){1,25}.(\w){1,25}(.|\w|$)((\w){1,25}|$)
```

Though this does not match the one in R example, with nor without extra escaping. In addition, regex in R example is marked as a raw string (`r"..."`)  but in R one should also use starting & closing sequence  (i.e. `r"(...)"`, more details in R help, `?Quotes`).

```r
emails <- c("javad.rasooli@bpmn.edu",
             "education@world.gov",
             "babak.pirooz@peace.org",
             "invalid.edu",
             "sadeghi@apbarez.edu",
             "hassaneskandari@codeman.ir")

emails[grep(pattern=r"((\w){1,25}(.|\w){1,25}@(\w){1,25}.(\w){1,25}(.|\w|$)((\w){1,25}|$))", ,x=emails)]
#> [1] "javad.rasooli@bpmn.edu"     "education@world.gov"       
#> [3] "babak.pirooz@peace.org"     "sadeghi@apbarez.edu"       
#> [5] "hassaneskandari@codeman.ir"
```

Or without raw string:

```r
emails[grep(pattern="(\\w){1,25}(.|\\w){1,25}@(\\w){1,25}.(\\w){1,25}(.|\\w|$)((\\w){1,25}|$)", x=emails)]
#> [1] "javad.rasooli@bpmn.edu"     "education@world.gov"       
#> [3] "babak.pirooz@peace.org"     "sadeghi@apbarez.edu"       
#> [5] "hassaneskandari@codeman.ir"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That is incredible . But the key point is when you are using regex by grep as a sting, if after pattern="bla bla bla..." you go to the next line because of the  R margin, it changes the string form. In below i describe the solution.

Answer (score 0):

That is incredible . But the key point is when you are using regex by grep as a sting, if after pattern="bla bla bla..." you go to the next line because of the  R margin, it changes the string form. In below i describe the solution.

For instance i want to save the string "Hello to programming lovers" into a string variable.

```
st<- "Hello to programming lovers"
st
```

the output:

```
[1] "Hello to programming lovers"
```

Now for any reason i repeat the above code in 2 lines instead of one line.

```
st<- "Hello to 
programming lovers"
st
```

the output:

```
[1] "Hello to \n    programming lovers"
```

This is natural when i write this code in two lines it gives me "character(0)".

```
`emails[grep(pattern =r"((\w){1,25}(\.|\w){0,25}
        (\w){1,25}@(\w){1,25}\.(\w){1,25}(\.|\w|$)((\w){1,25}|$))",x=emails)]
```

The output:

```
character(0)
```

Meanwhile when you use it in just one line or use with "paste" command with sep=""
it gives you desired result.

This is simple but ticky!.